# SOAP Client/Proxy Warning and Errors inside JBOSS Server not outside

Tags: java, soap, jboss, cxf

I'm working on implementing a SOAP service client from a specific vendor. There have been about 7 of these or so that I've come across each with their own challenges. However, with this specific instance, I've encountered a new problem.

Outside of my jboss server I can get the client implementation to run just fine, there are no problems at all. Insdie jboss/wildfly 8 though, I get a warning followed directly by and error when making the SOAP calls (see below).

I have a few questions that I am having trouble tracking down, listed most importance first.

1. How can I find out what operation is causing this error inside of the PhaseInterceptorChain, and is it the reason I am getting my Error?
2. The fault string, I can easily just add the content-type and so forth, but why would I have to do this? Shouldn't client already be doing this?
3. We specifically try to avoid apache cxf whenever possible. I don't explicitly see it being called anywhere in my source code or the source code generated with ws-import. We also don't even have it in our build path. Why is apache cxf popping up all over the place with these errors?

Start Warning:

```
2016-11-30 12:46:21,213 WARNING [org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain] Interceptor for {http:<removed url>/}<removed class>/<removed class>#{http://<removed url>/}<removed method> has thrown exception, unwinding now: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
    at java.util.AbstractMap.put(AbstractMap.java:209) [rt.jar:1.8.0_65]
    at org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.interceptor.SoapPreProtocolOutInterceptor.setSoapAction(SoapPreProtocolOutInterceptor.java:122)
    at org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.interceptor.SoapPreProtocolOutInterceptor.handleMessage(SoapPreProtocolOutInterceptor.java:63)
    at org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.interceptor.SoapPreProtocolOutInterceptor.handleMessage(SoapPreProtocolOutInterceptor.java:47)
    at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:272)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.doInvoke(ClientImpl.java:570)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:479)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:382)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:335)
    at org.apache.cxf.frontend.ClientProxy.invokeSync(ClientProxy.java:96)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsClientProxy.invoke(JaxWsClientProxy.java:135)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy154.<removed metho>(Unknown Source)
```

Start Error:

```
2016-11-30 12:46:21,257 ERROR [com.<removed class>] Fault string, and possibly fault code, not set: javax.xml.ws.soap.SOAPFaultException: Fault string, and possibly fault code, not set
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsClientProxy.invoke(JaxWsClientProxy.java:157)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy154.<removed metho>(Unknown Source)
    removed misc lines
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
        at java.util.AbstractMap.put(AbstractMap.java:209) [rt.jar:1.8.0_65]
        at org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.interceptor.SoapPreProtocolOutInterceptor.setSoapAction(SoapPreProtocolOutInterceptor.java:122)
        at org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.interceptor.SoapPreProtocolOutInterceptor.handleMessage(SoapPreProtocolOutInterceptor.java:63)
        at org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.interceptor.SoapPreProtocolOutInterceptor.handleMessage(SoapPreProtocolOutInterceptor.java:47)
        at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:272)
        at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.doInvoke(ClientImpl.java:570)
        at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:479)
        at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:382)
        at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:335)
        at org.apache.cxf.frontend.ClientProxy.invokeSync(ClientProxy.java:96)
        at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsClientProxy.invoke(JaxWsClientProxy.java:135)
        ... 10 more
```

Any help is greatly appreciated. I did try to scour the internet (stackoverflow, jboss developer, etc.) before posting.

Comment: Well turns out cxf is layered pretty deep in our jboss modules, so I guess that answers how it's finding classes to use.

Answer (score 0):

I've found article about this issue
http://mariemjabloun.blogspot.com/2013/10/javalangunsupportedoperationexception.html

Actually this interceptor tries to add new header to your request and if you have code like that

```
bp.getRequestContext().put(
    MessageContext.HTTP_REQUEST_HEADERS,
    Collections.singletonMap("Cookie", Collections.singletonList(yourCookieString)
);
```

you should change immutable singleton map to the mutable one (e.g. HashMap)